# Unity3D: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I want to access Hero.class variable "aspect" from laserController.class, but I receive an error message : `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Hero.class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {

public float aspect = 0.1f;
void Update () {

    }
}
```

laserController.class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class laserController : MonoBehaviour {

public float health = 0f;
//public float aspect = 0.1f;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "enemy"){
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
 }      

void Update () {

    Hero direction = gameObject.GetComponent<Hero>();

    //LaserHealth
    health += Time.deltaTime;

    if(health > 7f){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    } 
    //problem in here
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * -direction.aspect);

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your `Hero` component isn't attached to the same `GameObject` where `laserController` is attached to. 
If you want to force that condition you can use a `RequireComponentAttribute`:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Hero))]
public class laserController : MonoBehaviour
```

Some other unrelated consideration:

- Defining a empty `Update` method is useless and has performances overhead
- Try to follow consistence naming conventions for classes (camel case: `laserController -> LaserController`)